# Is there a particular word for the entrance or door of a bird's cage?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a particular word for the entrance or door of a bird's cage? I wouldn't use either word and they don't sound right, so I was wondering if there was a more widely used word to refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have often seen it referred to as a "door" or "cage door". I can't think of any special term for such a device. "cage door" would probably be the most usual term.